# Inputs print without text inside them, but are visible on the screen

Tags: html, css, text, printing, input

I have a problem with a project that I have been working on for a while now. When I open an entry, the inputs all have data in them. However when I go to actually print the entry (using the print-mode, CTRL+P), I notice that the **select**, and **textarea** fields are missing the selected or input text on **paper**. What's going on here? I have googled for hours and can't come up with anything relevant... help! Thanks!

[Link to Project (Click "Demo" to create a session - required)](http://www.stratusbase.com/)

[Link to Entry (Click this after you click the 1st link)](http://www.stratusbase.com/entry.php?e=7322ea7ae7bff0ab69543c19735fb40dd248724929adee40b7c93e3b4dab9863)

**Update** : Before now I have just been using Google Chrome to test printing. However, when I tried FireFox, it printed alright, is there anything special I need to do to get Chrome to work??...

**RESOLUTION** :  I am using jQuery and I found that by removing the **ui-corner-all** class from the inputs before printing, I could then print. Thanks anyways!

Comment: 'Missing' isn't a very good tag. HTML would be a more suitable keyword. Also, it looks fine in Firefox - you need to tell us what browser you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESOLUTION:** I'm using jQuery and I found that by removing the `ui-corner-all` class from the inputs before printing, I could then print. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Internet Explorer, then [this discussion thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/iewebdevelopment/thread/cee4833c-5511-4eb7-aacf-349ee94e1e80) may help you (summary: IE can get confused when printing malformed docs).  Check your doctype tag matches your output (the [w3c markup validator](http://validator.w3.org/) is very useful)

**Edit** - I see you're using chrome, but I suggest you still check your page is well formed :)

Comment: I figured it out, it was jQuery's ui-corner-all class that was messing it up, thanks for the help either way!!